# Python Script error in function ERROR 000539: SyntaxError

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I am receiving the following error; is it a simple syntax issue with the Calculate field because I'm not seeing anything missing.

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

```py
def calculate_pop(boundary, area_numbe, community):
   arcpy.Clip_analysis(bgs_places,boundary, r'in_memory\BG_Clip_temp')
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'in_memory\BG_Clip_temp','Pop_Layer')    
   arcpy.AddField_management('Pop_Layer','BGAREA','DOUBLE')
   arcpy.CalculateField_management('Pop_Layer','BGAREA','!shape.area!','PYTHON')
   arcpy.AddField_management('Pop_Layer','TOTPOP_17','LONG')
   #How to calculate Total Population
   arcpy.CalculateField_management('Pop_Layer','TOTPOP_17','((!TOTPOP_CY!*(!BGAREA!/!AREA!))','PYTHON')
   stats_temp=r'in_memory\Place_'+boundary+'_Temp_Pop_Statistics'
   arcpy.AddField_management('Pop_Layer','TOTPOP_17','LONG')
   arcpy.Statistics_analysis('Pop_Layer', stats_temp,"BGAREA;TOTPOP_17", "")

totpop_table=calculate_pop('Bndry_Lyr', area_numbe, community)
append_stats(totpop_table)
```

Comment: Fix the formatting so we can see what you are doing. How are you calling the function?

Comment: @Hornbydd what line? its erroring on the Calculate field and there isn't one missing.

Comment: Apologies I misread the line! Comment removed.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you were correct, I had too many '()'

Answer (score 1):

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management('Pop_Layer','TOTPOP_17','!TOTPOP_CY!*(!BGAREA!/!AREA!)','PYTHON')
```

This is the corrected line of code, where I removed parenthesis that was not needed.